# Unable to connect to github.com on push and pull

Tags: git, github

Why does this error happen when I try to push to github?
I have checked with ping and tracert and the Github connection is well 
but when I want to push something to Github this error is displayed.
Please tell me what I should do to solve this error.

I am using Windows 7 and HTTPS with Github:

```
$ git push origin master fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No error
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `git remote -v` tell you?

Comment: Do you have the rights to access the repo?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you get that error if you use `https://` instead of `git://` for your repository.

```
"https://". insteadOf git://
git config --global url.
```

Or change that URL in your `.git/config` file.

Comment: I have used https. I am using broad band connection , is there any issue for broadband

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct repository URL? And no mistakes in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am using https://github.com/manozdebnath/git.git this url and what the configuration you told about?

Comment: try the `git remove -v`` command with verbose mode to get some errors and informations.

Comment: Hi, I have found this
MANOZ@MANOZ-PC ~/Desktop/git (master)
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/manozdebnath/git.git

MANOZ@MANOZ-PC ~/Desktop/git (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  git://github.com/manozdebnath/git.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/manozdebnath/git.git (push)

Is it ok